# Kill all processes except,

Tags: linux, macos, unix

I'm trying to login as a different user but it takes too much memory, I don't want the user to run all processes just one app, but I want to switch between users without logging off. I want the user to run an specific app but only that, and kill all unnecessary processes, ie logging in runs all startup process again and loads desktop etc.. clogging and eating a lot of memory. I'd like to kill all and leave the app and whats necessary for me to switch to the user, ie desktop

Comment: Use `sudo` to run a single command as another user.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.